# What does LINUX stands for

Tags: linux, history

Does the term "LINUX" stands for anything. Until now, I was of the opinion that this term is derived from "LINUS". However, some articles on internet give following:

```
Linux = Linus Torvald's Unix
Linux = Linux Is Not Unix
```

What is correct here? Kindly guide me in this respect.

Comment: Would you edit your post to add some links to the articles where these interpretations were presented?

Comment: https://www.abbreviations.com/LINUX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux is the kernel’s name, based on Linus Torvalds’ first name — a portmanteau of “Linus” and “x” in reference to Unix.

*Just for Fun: The Story of an Accidental Revolutionary* mentioned that Linus initially wanted to call the kernel Freax, having considered Linux and dismissed as too egotistical. Ari Lemmke, who administered the server where Linux was initially hosted for distribution, didn’t like the “Freax” name, and used the Linux name instead without even asking Linus Torvalds.

See [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#Naming) for details and references.